Intermittent issue with AAD Authentication, once in a while freezes on `Checking login state ...`
Most of cases works well, but once in a while freezes on Checking login state ... message with no error. No login window displayed as the token is in a cookie (previously logged in)
It's a standard Azure AAD login feature with a button that redirects user to authentication/login, this is added by blazor wasm workload, and I do not remember modifying it. Configuration looks fine
    "AzureAd": {
        "ClientId": "...",
        "Authority": "...",
        "ValidateAuthority": false
    },

piece of code in the Blazor page that starts sign on is
<NotAuthorized>
    <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>

It works as expected in most of cases under debugger, except for few occasions when it hangs forever on the message Checking login state ... (blank page), need to stop the debugger and restart app again. Usually it's not fixed from the first restart, need to run multiple attempts, neither server not client error occur, Edge console looks clean. Not sure how to troubleshoot the error and what might be wrong. Could it be a glitch on AAD service side, maybe the service goes temp unavailable?

Hi, could you please share which .net version you are using and the related nuget packages you are using in yor blazor wsam app? By the way, could you pls try the redirect mode instead of the default popup mode?  builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>{builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd",options.ProviderOptions.Authentication); options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";});

.net 8.0, Web assembly packages of ver 8.0.4. I'll try the redirect mode and let you know. Since the issue intermittent, it takes time to realize if it helps or not. Thanks

looks like "redirect" option gets it fixed. Interesting. Could anyone explain?

I don't know to be honest, I faced similar issue before and I tried to fix, then the redirect helped me solved it and that's why I shared it with you. I only had an assumption that it might related to cookie setting....
